# NODE.JS - How to invoke correctly next() after multi REQUESTS are done?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I am running over an ARRAY using forEach() loop.
For every element , I need to invoke a request.
I want to call the next() after ALL invoked requests are done (assume I have at least a 100 requests to invoke).

Any ideas how to approach this?

Here is a little sample code to demonstrate my question -

```js
var arr = ["A" , "B", "C" , "D" , "E"];
arr.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
 var options = { 
        method: 'GET',
        url:"some_url",
        headers: {...} 
  };
  request(options, function (error, response, body)
  {
    if (error)  {next(error);}

    // DO_SOMETHING based on arrayItem

  }); // end of request()
});  //end of forEach

// WHERE should I place the next()?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can do this.  Since all the calls to `request()` are asynchronous and thus will finish sometime in the future long after your loop has finished, you will have to keep track of them somehow.  I'll show two methods, one using Promises and one using a counter.

**Promises**

```
// create wrapper function that returns a promise
function requestPromise(options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(options, function(error, response, body) {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            resolve({response: response, body: body});
        });
    });
}

var arr = ["A" , "B", "C" , "D" , "E"];

Promise.all(arr.map(function(item) {
    // create options object here for each request
    var options = { 
        method: 'GET',
        url:"some_url",
        headers: {...} 
    };

    return requestPromise(options);

})).then(function(results) {
    // process results here

    // call next() here because all processing is now done
    next();
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error happened
    next(err);
});
```

**Manual Counter**

```
var arr = ["A" , "B", "C" , "D" , "E"];
var errDone = false;
var cntr = 0;
arr.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
    var options = { 
        method: 'GET',
        url:"some_url",
        headers: {...} 
  };
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error)  {
        if (!errDone) {
            // latch error so we don't call next(error) multiple times
            errDone = true;
            next(error);
        }
    } else {
        // process result here

        // check if this is the last response
        ++cntr;
        if (cntr === arr.length) {
            // all responses done here
            next();
        }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Hey @jfriend00 - thanks a lot , it really helped me to understand this concept which was totally new to me.
Just a small follow up question about your solution - on the catch() method, will the error include the specific response of the failed request, with all it's details (so I will know which request failed) , or will it only include the err message of the response?

Comment: @GadiBenAmram - It will include the `error` value from the `request()` that failed first.  If you want, you can include more info by just constructing your own object with more info in it and call `reject(yourObj)` instead of `reject(error)`.

Comment: got it! Thanks again @jfriend00  , it really really helped :-).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use Promises for this.

Every element in the array would be a Promise and after everything is done a `.then()` function is invoked.

For your case:

Promise.all() would be the best solution.https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Usage:

```
var A = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var options = { 
        method: 'GET',
        url:"some_url",
        headers: {...} 
request(options, function (error, response, body)
  {
    if (error)  {reject()};
    resolve();
  }); 
});
var B = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var options = { 
        method: 'GET',
        url:"some_url",
        headers: {...} 
request(options, function (error, response, body)
  {
    if (error)  {reject()};
    resolve();
  }); 
}); 
var arr = [A , B, C , D , E];
Promise.all(arr).then(next());
```

Comment: Hey @Hardik-Jain , thanks a lot.
I chose to mark another answer is the solution since it also helped to to address the mapping of a big array (over 100 elements) , but your answer also helped me to understand how to approach the solution and I really appreciate you took the time and effort to write such a great response.
Thanks again :-).
Gadi.

Comment: Glad it helped! :D