# How Do You Handle Multiple GET Requests Using Node+Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous

I have an application that needs to request NASA's Astronomy Picture of the Day 5 times and then it will load a webpage displaying those images. I then request a different site (the LaunchLibrary API) to get the next 5 launches. My problem is when I have to display the image; sometimes it will display 2 images, sometimes 5, sometimes none. This is obviously just the asynchronous nature of GET requests but I was wondering if there is a way to wait for the NASA pictures before rendering the page.

Here is an example of what I have.

```
app.get("/index", function(req, res) {
    /**Requesting NASA's Astronomy Picture of the Day**/
    var apod_url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=[My API Key]"
    var apod_img_urls = [];
    var curr_moment = moment();
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var appended_url = apod_url + "&date=" + curr_moment.subtract(i, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        request(appended_url, function(error, reponse, body) {
            if(!error && reponse.statusCode == 200) {
                var img_json = JSON.parse(body);
                apod_img_urls.push(img_json.hdurl);
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
    /**************************************************/

    var url = "https://launchlibrary.net/1.3/launch/next/5";
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
       if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           var data = JSON.parse(body);
           res.render("index", {data: data, apod_img_urls: apod_img_urls});
       } else {
           console.log(error);
       }
    });
});
```

I've also tried putting the loop of image requests inside of the if-statement in my request for the next 5 launches and that caused none of the images to show up. Is there a way I can "synchronize" these requests so all of the images return before rendering the page?

Comment: FYI, you can switch the `request` library to the `request-promise` library and then use the promise-based solution mentioned in here: [How can I wati for set of asynchronous callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004112/how-can-i-wait-for-set-of-asynchronous-callback-functions).

Comment: Also relevant: [node.js - How to invoke correctly next() after multi requests are done?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479636/node-js-how-to-invoke-correctly-next-after-multi-requests-are-done/43481615#43481615)